# Unable to get Single Object data from array in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am new in react-native.I am unable to get "present" data from my API and I am getting an error "cannot read property present" so i just want to get my API response.Here is my api data and please check my code too.

```
{
 "message": "present in this month",
  "data": [
    {
        "present": 10
    }
   ],
  "status": "1"
 }


  async componentDidMount() { 
 try {
            const DEMO_TOKEN = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn');
            if (DEMO_TOKEN != null) {
                console.log('Token', DEMO_TOKEN);
                fetch('http://104.197.28.169:3000/userPresentInThisMonth', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + DEMO_TOKEN,
                    },                     
                })
                    .then(response => response.json())                     
                    .then(responseJson => {
                          alert(responseJson)              
                        console.log(responseJson);
                        this.setState({
                            presentmonthdata : responseJson,
                        });
                    });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            console.error(error);
        }
   }
```

This is my Text value.

```
   {this.state.presentmonthdata.data[0] &&
    <Text   style={{color: 'grey',fontSize: 30,   fontWeight: 'bold',  }}>
                            {this.state.presentmonthdata.data[0].present}
                  </Text>
```

}

Comment: try ```this.state.presentmonthdata.data[0].present```

Comment: I am getting an error "cannot read property '0' of undefined " .

Comment: since you are fetch data from API you should wait until data load. ```this.state.presentmonthdata.data[0] && this.state.presentmonthdata.data[0].present```

Comment: i got an same error

Comment: I did update my code but i got an same error please check

Comment: could you share the value of ```this.state.presentmonthdata```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

change:

```
{this.state.presentmonthdata.data[0] &&
    <Text style={{color: 'grey',fontSize: 30,   fontWeight: 'bold',  }}>
                            {this.state.presentmonthdata.data[0].present}
                  </Text>
```

to

```
<Text>
{this.state.presentmonthdata.data!= undefined ? this.state.presentmonthdata.data[0].present: null}
</Text>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

the solution is

```
{this.state.presentmonthdata.data[0]}
```

Comment: I am getting an error "cannot read property '0' of undefined "

Comment: {
 "message": "present in this month",
  "data": [
    {
        "present": 10
    }
   ],
  "status": "1"
 }

Comment: the problem  is you didn't parse JSON In the response and you setState a JSON

Comment: please use response.json()  before return response

Comment: your value and key is wrapped with " " and it is the problem

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
`{this.state.data.length > 0 ? this.state.data[0].present : 0;}`

I'm guessing data is either a blank array or another data type...